# Pandas dataframe add new column based on if other columns have data or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
x y z
1 2 3
na 1 4
na na 5
```

Now I want to add another column a whose value depend on x, y and z. If x is available then a would be "yes". If it is na then it will check y. If y is available then, a would be "no", otherwise a would be same as z(if it is available otherwise it will be 0). I have the following function in R:

```
cur_sta <- function(data){

    sta <- ifelse(!is.na(data$x),"yes",    
        ifelse(!is.na(data$y),"no",    
        ifelse(!is.na(data$z),data$z,0)))

}
```

How can I achieve the same in python?

**EDIT:**

I tried the following:

```
conditions = [
        (not pd.isnull(data["x"].item())),
        (not pd.isnull(data["y"].item())),
        (not pd.isnull(data["z"].item()))]
    choices = ['yes', 'no', data["z"]]
    data['col_sta'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='0')
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @jezrael The question you linked did not help me much. So please reopen this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) for test non missing values:

```
conditions = [data["x"].notna(),
              data["y"].notna(),
              data["z"].notna()]
choices = ['yes', 'no', data["z"]]
data['col_sta'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='0')
print (data)
     x    y  z col_sta
0  1.0  2.0  3     yes
1  NaN  1.0  4      no
2  NaN  NaN  5       5
```